# Alternative to musikcube on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, music, vlc

I like music to be played on the background and changing tracks by keyboard shortcut like in musikcube: http://www.musikcube.com/wiki/Preferences.
Is there an alternative for musikcube on Mac OS X Lion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SizzlingKeys](http://yellowmug.com/sk4it/) may be of help here.

Comment: There are so many apps to control iTunes via keyboard, it's almost an embarrassment of riches. Quicksilver, Launchbar, Butler .. to name but a few. This is nice and cheap though.

Answer (score 1):

I use [CoverSutra](http://sophiestication.com/coversutra/) - not free, but pretty cheap, and I like the ability to have the album cover displayed on the desktop.